# Apache redirect based on hostname

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I have multiple hostnames resolving to a single machine, e.g.:

- build.mydomain.com
- www.mydomain.com
- jira.mydomain.com
- mydomain.com

Is it possible to setup apache in order to redirect requests to each different hostname?

e.g:

- build.mydomain.com -> build.mydomain.com:8111,
- www.mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com:8080
- mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com:8080

The DNS records are setup to all point to the same machine, i just want to redirect to the right port given the hostname.

Cheers,

Edit:

Machine is debian w/ Apache2

Edit2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    redirect 301 / http://www.mydomain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName build.mydomain.com
    redirect 301 / http://build.mydomain.com:8111/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running multiple instances of Apache, each listening on a different port? Why? Virtual hosts will take care of everything.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: No, single instance of apache that I wanted to use to redirect requests.

Got multiple instances of tomcat running, e.g. TeamCity on 8111, tomcat on 8080 and JIRA on 8081.

I wanted to redirect to the respective port given the hostname.

Comment: how about mod-rewrite running on the apache:80 instance? possibly even apache as proxy but that sounds like far too much effort for a redirect.

Comment: I have it half working, using VirtualHost directive with a redirect 301 to the same hostname and different port. This should do for now.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

Follow the documentation about [canonical hostnames](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost) which lead to [`<If>` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#if) :

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'build.mydomain.com' && %{SERVER_PORT} -eq 80">
    RedirectMatch permanent /.* http://build.mydomain.com:8111
</If>

<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.mydomain.com' && %{SERVER_PORT} -eq 80">
    RedirectMatch permanent /.* http://www.mydomain.com:8080
</If>

...
```

Comment: Not for apache 2.2. Any ideas how i can do it for apache 2.2? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I doubt using redirect is winning strategy for what you're trying to do. I'd recommend using mod_proxy to create a reverse proxy which will hide the way you've built your system.

And if I had the choice, I would use something more lightweight and more convenient to configure, like Perlbal.