# How do I redirect subdomains to a different port on the same server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, apache-2.4, subdomain

I have some subdomains I want to redirect to specific ports on the same server.
Say I have

```
dev.mydomain.com
```

I want `dev.mydomain.com` to transparently redirect to `mydomain.com:8080` and I want to preserve the original sub-domain name the url of the browser.

How do I do this with Apache 2.2? I have Apache 2.2 running on default port `80`. I can't figure out the write configuration to get this to happen.

I have already set up `dev.mydomain.com` to resolve in DNS to `mydomain.com`.

> This is for an intranet development server that has a non-routable ip
>   address so I am not so concerned about exploits and security that
>   would compromise a publicly facing server.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

### Solution

Here is what I finally came up with after being set in the right direction by Miles Erickson. I wanted the address bar to reflect the original subdomain/domain of the request and not the redirected server and port, but he put me on the right path to Google up a solution using `VirtualHost` and I finally found a solution that included the use of `mod_proxy`.

First, make sure `mod_proxy` is enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer
sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Next, add the following to your site config (e.g., `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For everyone who this answer didn't work for, keep in mind that you have to enable mods `mod_proxy` as well as `proxy_http`.

Comment: What about in `nginx` ?

Comment: For macOSX, don't waste hours like me trying to edit `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. My `httpd.conf`wasn't looking at this vhosts file by default. I had to add my new conf to `/private/etc/apache2/other` ([ref](https://jasonmccreary.me/articles/configure-apache-virtualhost-mac-os-x/)). Everything else above worked as is.

Answer (score 16):

Run the following line on terminal (specify your domain and sub domain name correctly)

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.example.com.conf
```

Paste the following code and change as your requirement

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        ServerName subdomain.example.com
        ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
        ProxyRequests Off

        #ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        <Location />
                ProxyPreserveHost On
                ProxyPass http://example.com:8080/
                ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:8080/
        </Location>
     # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
     #SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

Run the following lines on terminal (specify your domain and sub domain name correctly)

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2ensite subdomain.example.com.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Is there any essential difference between this and the accepted answer?

Comment: Most of the people forget to add `sudo a2enmod proxy_http` so they face difficulties on running properly. Also I try to give full process from start to end in a sequence to help more acculturate. Thanks for your question.

Comment: Thanks kasperd for asking it's just a little bit tweaking for people like me who forget some little things which are essential like sudo a2enmod proxy and sudo a2enmod proxy_http command after creating the configuration file.

Comment: This just does not work for me. 'sudo a2enmod subdomain.domain.com.conf' says "ERROR: Module x.y.z does not exist!" Does it have to be mentioned in the 'default' configuration?

Comment: @dirk-schumacher can you please give your configuration file details here so that we can identify the exact error cause.

Comment: Correction in registering subdomain
 `sudo a2ensite sub.yourdomain.com`

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that dev.mydomain.com can be resolved to mydomain.com's IP, you could add the following to your httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.mydomain.com
    redirect / http://mydomain.com:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Relevant Apache documentation:

1. [Guide to creating name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)
2. [Core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html), including [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) and [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)
3. [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

Related question:
[Apache redirect based on hostname](https://serverfault.com/questions/99108/apache-redirect-based-on-hostname)

(Note: the original version of this answer incorrectly suggested the use of RedirectMatch, which, as @ChrisS helpfully pointed out, cannot parse the domain portion of the URL.)

Comment: see my self provided answer for what I actually used, which is this idea of VirtualHost with mod_proxy to preserve the original host instead of doing a redirect. This is an internal server so I am not concerned with security or exploits of mod_proxy.

Comment: Found numerous other suggestions but this ultimately worked for me on Windows Server 2008 R2/Apache 2.2.25.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that in your brother, you don't stay on the first domain, you get a 302 to the second.

Answer (score 5):

Add in your main vhost configuration the following lines:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example:8080/
```

Note that this requires mod_proxy on Apache.

Comment: This is not a redirect; it proxies the connection. Enabling mod_proxy can be extremely easy to exploit if you aren't very careful configuring it. I would highly recommend against this.

Comment: He doesn't want a redirect, as per his OP. He wants the original URL to remain in the address bar; this means using either mod_proxy or mod_rewrite, and y'all better avoid mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for mod_rewrite. [Here's the link to Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) which includes many examples for [basic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) and [advanced](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html) configurations..

And if you're unable to interpret the documentation yourself, try adding this to httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]        
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:8080$1 [R=301]
```

And if that's not a clear example, here's a [link to a mod_rewrite beginners guide](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) too.

Comment: I'm on shared hosting. Rewrite is the only option. I can create a .htaccess file, but not a proxy or virtual host.