# How can the mod_proxy be harmful?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I would like to apply [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server) to my own server.

However, it will not be an internal server, so I'm concerned about security. The linked question tells that the mod_proxy can be easily misconfigured. What is so dangerous ? And what's the 'good' way to configure it ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can find a pretty good explanation of the security problems in the official [mod_proxy documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html). Generally speaking, you will definitely want to limit either the allowed clients (running a forward proxy) or the allowed target hosts (running a reverse proxy).

Otherwise, you would allow arbitrary clients to request arbitrary resources through your host.