# Couldn't find IP address for subdomain after Apache's reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain

I would like to use the Jenkins docker container, that allows an access from localhost:8080, from a subdomain, such as jenkins.subdomain.me

I came accross [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server), applied it to my situation, activated the `proxy_http` mod for Apache, then restarted without any trouble. However, when I tried to reach the subdomain I just created, I got the following error:

Can not find the IP address for the server jenkins.mydomain.me

Here is how I set up my virtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName jenkins.mydomain.me
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't know if anything is missing, or if I need to add something to my domain's name DNS

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if anything is missing, or if I need to add something to
>   my domain's name DNS

you should create a dns entry for jenkins.mydomain.me pointing your machine ip or if you are just working 'local' you should modify the hosts file (/etc/hosts)
adding an entry using localhost or your network interface

```
127.0.0.1 jenkins.mydomain.me
```

Comment: That seems so obvious now! I needed to add a new entry for a subdomain from my domain provider, thank you!