# How to redirect a port and use a subdomain?

Tags: port, subdomain, redirection

I know my problem has already been described (see [How do I redirect subdomains to a different port on the same server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server) for ex) but as I can't make it work on my side, I ask for some help again.

I have an Apache server running.
I can access to all the different web softwares which are running on this server trough subdomains.
Ex :
https://nextcloud.my_domain.fr
https://roundcube.my_domain.fr
...

At my ISP provider side, I have the following :

```
nextcloud   A   10800   xx.xx.xx.xx
subsonic    A   10800   xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I said "all" softwares but this is not true. I can't do the same for sub-domains I want to redirect to specific ports.
For ex, subsonic needs port 4040.
I can access to subsonic with :
https://my_domain.fr/subsonic
but not with :
https://subsonic.my_domain.fr

I can remove the port 4040 in the field, this is better than nothing, but I want more :)

I have the same issue for filebrowser (port 8082), guacamole (port 8080), ...

To remove the port in the address field, I have the following configuration files in the directory /etc/httpd/conf/sites.d :

File 00_default_vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName my_domain.fr
   ServerAdmin xuo@my_domain.fr
   RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

RewriteEngine On
```

File 00_default_ssl_vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # general configuration
    ServerAdmin xuo@my_domain.fr
    ServerName my_domain.fr

    # SSL configuration
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/certificates/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/certificates/server.pem
    SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
    SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
    "%V %t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.my_domain\.fr
    RewriteCond /var/www/html/%1 -l
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/$1 [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

File guacamole.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    <Location /guacamole/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.14:8080/guacamole/ flushpackets=on
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.14:8080/guacamole/
    </Location>

    <Location /guacamole/websocket-tunnel>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ProxyPass ws://192.168.0.14:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
    ProxyPassReverse ws://192.168.0.14:8080/guacamole/websocket-tunnel
    </Location>
</IfModule>
```

File subsonic.conf :

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    <Proxy http://192.168.0.14:4040/subsonic/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /subsonic/ http://192.168.0.14:4040/subsonic/
    ProxyPassReverse /subsonic/ http://192.168.0.14:4040/subsonic/
</IfModule>
```

File nextcloud.conf (no need for port redirection) :

```
Alias /nextcloud /var/www/html/nextcloud
<Directory /var/www/html/nextcloud>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The "best" I could achieve (and I don't remember how), was to get the subsonic main page on both https://subsonic.my_domain.fr **AND** https://my_domain.fr

Does anyone know how to make the subdomain + port redirection work together ?
Note that I have several subdomains, so my goal is to be able to use nextcloud.my_domain.fr, subsonic.my_domain.fr, guacamole.my_domain.fr, ...

Regards.

Xuo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I forward requests from my web server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1035016/how-can-i-forward-requests-from-my-web-server)

Comment: `my_domain.fr` is not a valid part of an hostname. Don't obfuscate needlessly and more than that don't obfuscate badly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I didn't see I had some answers.
I'll have a look at "How can I forward requests from my web server?".

Regards.

Xuo.